# Does anti-Hermtian matrices from a vector space?

Tags: vector-spaces

My book states that $n\times n$ anti-Hermitian matrices $T^\dagger = -T$ form a real vector space. But the identity matrix is not anti-Hermitian and hence doesn't belong to this set. Is my book wrong?

Comment: Do you believe $\mathbb R^3$ forms a real vector space?  It doesn't contain the identity matrix either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No the book is not wrong. It is easy to check that the set is closed with respect to matrix addition and scalar multiplication. It is the zero matrix that must belong to any subspace. Indeed the set containing only the zero matrix is a subspace!

Answer (score 1):

Which axiom of vector spaces says the identity matrix must be an element of the vector space?

You may be confusing the identity matrix, which is a *multiplicative identity*  ($MI = IM = I$) with the zero vector, the *additive identity* $0+M = M+0 = M$, which *does* have to be in any vector space.

Comment: The multiplication identity.

Comment: Don't tell me the "one" in the multiplicative identity axiom is a scalar?

Comment: @nougako Yep it's a scalar ;)

Comment: Yeah I mean $1v=v$.

Comment: @nougako Yup, it's called a *real* vector space because the set of scalars you can multiply a vector by is the set of real numbers.  In general, a vector space need not have any concept of multiplying two elements (vectors) together.